# Public code snippet library?

Tags: feature-request

I think a code snippet library would a great addition to SO. Snippets could be voted up / down, etc.

Personally, I would love a place where I can keep useful code snippets online. There are services out there, but I'd like a place I visit on a regular basis anyway.

Comment: I like this idea in a general sort of way, but I'm not sure SO is the right place to implement it. What does it have to do with Q&A?

Comment: I'm seeing a lot of code snippets in chat and questions.  But I think there should be a systemwide way to tie all your snippets, and those you're interested in to your profile.  Just for instance.  Build a taged, searchable, browseable library, for instance.

Comment: You mean like code.google.com?

Comment: I like the idea too, but I don't think SO is the right forum for it. It needs a whole different kind of moderation and attention to work well

Answer (score 6):

I suspect any value that you might hope to get from the voting will be swamped by "this is fun!" votes for comments, variable or subprogram names, deep but rarely useful hacks like the quake sqrt approximation, etc, etc, etc...

The way to beat this problem would, of course, be to group the snippets by the problem they solves, which would end up looking an awful lot like questions with answers.

Put me down as against.

Comment: Why would you assume the majority of voting would be whimsical?  And wouldn't it be up to the users to decide what's useful or not ( quake sqrt approximation probably wouldn't be useful to me for instance... )

Comment: @kervin: Take a look at the [highest voted questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes) on Stack Overflow. More people vote for things that are *fun* than for stuff that is *good* in a technically helpful sense. It's the source of all the big, enduring conflict on the site, and has survived repeated attempts to "fix" it.